# DDD: where do persistence-entity update logic?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have two domain entities:

```
class Foo {
   int Id {get;}
   string Name {get;}
}
class FooBar : Foo {
   RuleEnum Rule {get;}   
   string NewName {get;}
   int OrderId {get;}
}
```

And single persistence model for them:

```
class FooInDb {
   int Id {get;set;}
   int Rule {get;set;}
   string Name {get;set;}
   string NewName {get;set;}
   int? OrderId {get;set;}
}
```

I have application service, converting api-binding models to domains models (from `IEnumarable<Api.Foo>` to `IEnumarable<FooBar>`). Validation of some business rules occures in `FooBar` ctor. What I need next: load all `FooInDb`s from db and update its fields, according to:

```
void Update(FooBar fooBar, FooInDb fooInDb)
{
   fooInDb.Rule = fooBar.Rule;

   if (fooBar.Rule == RuleEnum.New){
     fooInDb.NewName = fooBar.NewName;
     fooInDb.OrderId = null;
   }
   else {
     fooInDb.NewName = null;
     fooInDb.OrderId = fooBar.OrderId;
   }
}
```

Should this decision be placed in some domain-service? (Personally I do not want domain-service project to reference persistence-models project.) If not, how fine will be to place it in repository and call from application-service?

Comment: As you say, the domain project shouldn't reference the persistence project, because it shouldn't care about the technical persistence details. Therefore, put the mapping between domain model and the database into your persistence project.

Comment: I move decision about what to map into factory methods in `FooBar`: `FooBar.New()` and `FooBar.NotNew()`

Comment: But then it is within the domain project, which you should avoid

Answer (score 0):

Your domain model seems quite CRUD-oriented and anemic, but that is another story.

**The persistence layer shouldn't be making decisions about the model's state**. If the state should change based on the `Rule` then the model is responsible to reflect that.

The only thing the persistency layer should know here is how to persist the various representations of the same kind of entity, by mapping the model state as is to the persistence model.

E.g. where `persistenceFramework` is assumed to be anything that handles the persistence of your persistence model. Also not that I'm not a C# programmer.

```
    public void Save(Foo foo) {
        FooInDb dbFoo = persistenceFramework.FindById(foo.Id);

        Map(dbFoo, foo as dynamic);

        persistenceFramework.Save(dbFoo);
    }

   private void Map(FooInDb dbFoo, Foo foo) {
       //Foo mapping logic
   }

   private void Map(FooInDb dbFoo, FooBar foo) {
       //FooBar mapping logic
   }
```

Comment: if repository pattern is used is it normal to have 2 DB lookups on simple update operations? First for model creation, and second when model is submitted for update?

Comment: @Tenek Well, the first lookup is obviously needed, but the second may not. For instance, some ORMs are keeping an identity map in memory in order to perform dirty checking rather than performing it against the DB to know what changes to persist.

Comment: makes sense, with our dumm legacy DAL second lookup will be necessary :(. This DAL don't even has session/transaction manager...